# VIDEO.JS - Player still streaming after the pause / stop command

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I'm trying to embed a [video.js](http://www.videojs.com/) video player on my website. I'm running a debian 7.5 / chrome / IceWeasel (thunderbird) station with jquery-1.10.2 for the test.

**Awaited features**

Playing a video from a list index.

I list the video files contained in a directory, setup the hyperlink for each of them as :

```
<a class="IndexItem" href="#" id="404467" type="video/mime-type" data-video="video-file_name.mp4">My video #1</a>
....
```

*The click event* is managed BY the javascript code.

when a video index is clicked, the corresponding source tag is dynamically created and the video player loaded.

**Issue**

The video is loaded and played succesfully but when I click the player stop button, the progress bar still move forward until the end of the stream is reached.

How can I fixed that ?

**Code excerpt**

*html*

```
<video class="video-js vjs-default-skin" height="480" id="video-player" width="640" poster="/images/bubble-logo.png">
 <source src="/path/to/my/video" type="video/mime-type"/>
 <h3>Your browser does not support the video tag</h3>
</video>
```

the *video/mime_type* can be video/mp4, video/webm or video/ogg

*javascript*

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //---------------------
    // Edit click event
    //---------------------

    $.each($(".IndexItem"), function(){

        $(this).click(function(event){

            event.preventDefault();

            // href data-video attribute contains the video file name
            // href type attribute contains the video mime-type
            var filename = $(this).attr("data-video");
            var mime = $(this).attr("type");            

            // removing previous sources
            $('#video-player').empty();

            playVideo(filename, mime);

           }); 
    });    

});


function playVideo(filename, mime) {

    // set set html source tag inside the video player div
    loadSource(filename, mime);

    videojs("video-player", {"controls":true}, function(){
      // Player (this) is initialized and ready.
    });

}

function loadSource(filename, mime){

    var source = $('<source src="/videos/' + filename + '" type="' + mime + '"/>');
    $('#video-player').append(source);

    var warning = $('<h3>Your browser does not support the video tag</h3>');
    $('#video-player').append(warning);

    console.log("Creating new source :" + source);

}
```

Perhaps my method is not the right one as I create a video player instance for each request (Doesn't seem to be really clean ...). Assuming it's not,  the problem regarding my issue is still relevant as it raised the first time I try to open a video after having the page reloaded.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Fix

It's an encoding issue of my video files with ffmpeg, frankly I don't remenber what was exactly the problem but now everything works fine !

First thing: to ensure the widest compliance it's advised to encode your original video in three different format :

- mp4
- webm
- ogg (ogv extension)

and then declaring them in the html tags as

```
<video height="480" id="video-1" width="640" poster="/images/video-1.jpg" controls="true" preload="true"><source src="/videos/video-1.ogv" type="video/ogg"/><source src="/videos/video-1.webm" type="video/webm/><source src="/videos/video-1.mp4" type="video/mp4"/><h3>Your browser does not support the video tag</h3></video>
```

*/videos must be a static web server mapping to /path/to/ (see bellow)*

The more difficult thing to do is to encode the video with the correct ffmpeg options. The video bit rate must not exceed the link capacity and the video display must be as smooth as possible.

I found out this settings after several days of testing that finally fit my needs  ... and also perharps yours.

I use .mp4 format as input as that's providen by my Contour Camera but ffmpeg should convert any other known format.

To check the available formable type in:

```
$ ffmpeg -formats
```

To encode my video with multiple outputs, I run

```
$ ffmpeg -i camvideo.mp4 -c:v libvpx -c:a libvorbis -s 4cif -b:v 256K -f webm /path/to/video-1.webm
$ ffmpeg -i camvideo.mp4 -c:v libx264 -s 4cif -preset slow -bufsize 4M -maxrate 256K -tune fastdecode,zerolatency -c:a copy -b:a 16K -f mp4 path/to/video-1.mp4
$ ffmpeg -y -i $1 -codec:v libtheora -s 4cif -qscale:v 7 -codec:a libvorbis -qscale:a 3 -f ogg  /path/to/video-1.ogv
```

Note that my environment is Debian 7.5 with ffmpeg 2.2.2 (compiled from sources) and that  the result may differ regarding your ffmpeg version ... I think.

Note : the mp4 source is also re-encoded to make it usable by web browser plugins and Be patient .. encoding is a huge CPU task.

Hope that helps.